# How does mongodb save mutlimedia files?

Tags: mongodb

How does a multimedia file get saved in mongodb database? How does mongodb save it in a form of  the documents?

Comment: The defalt is to use gridfs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

Answer (score -2):

`mongodb` splits the media files into small chunks of BSON.

Individual chunks then saved on the different sharded nodes and their information(metadata) is saved on `mongodb` configuration server.

Comment: Sharding is not required for GridFS. GridFS also splits it into small chunks of binary data, which is then stored in a field inside a special GridFS document. The whole document is stored as BSON.